# Raspberry Pi wifi won't work

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie

I just got my first Raspberry Pi today and I plugged in an Edimax WiFi USB adapter. It flashed blue a few times and then stopped. I am in the desktop and then I look at the upper right hand corner where the WiFi applet is. It says, "No wireless interface found" and it also says, "wlan0 not associated". I ran commands like `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`, and I tested if the Pi can detect the adapter. Both seem normal. Everything else like `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` is default. I am running Raspbian Jessie. Please help

Comment: What does `lsusb | grep -i edimax` return?  
In order to start solving your issue, the exact type of adapter has to be known and the above command should give that. If it doesn't return anything, just run `lsusb` and copy the line(s) you think should/could be your wireless adapter.

Comment: Update RPI firmware you can do this by following command: rpi-update

Comment: @U.Swap "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and it took me ages to figure it out
http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2012/08/17/how-to-fix-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-message-in-ubuntu-12-04/

`Network-manager` is not used on current version of Raspbian so you can ignore that.

- Install `rfkill`: `apt install rfkill`.
- Check if the adapter is soft-blocked: `rfkill list wlan`.  If so:

  ```
  rfkill unblock wlan
  ```

  According to some users this may be because `country` is not set properly in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

In case you haven't already found this guide on the foundation's forum, it's worth a look - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=44044

I had a similar issue with my original Pi (although not with a recent RPi 2), and the eventual solution was to give it a static IP address as step 4c (setting a static IP address) of the guide.

Need to add some code to /etc/network/interfaces; it should include these lines:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And below them we then add

```
iface default inet static
address 10.1.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.1.1
```

Comment: Your answer may become of little use if that link stops working. And if the guide is updated (so that step 4c becomes something else), it will become misleading.