# Edimax Wifi Adapter won't work

Tags: wifi, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I plugged in an Edimax N150 adapter. (I was using "Jessie"). In the upper right hand corner, there was a applet with two computers next to each other. I assumed that was the network symbol, but when I clicked on it, it said "No wireless interface found" and something like, "wlan not associated". I ran a few commands in the terminal and it showed that the kernel (Driver or something) was loaded for it, it could detected by the raspberry Pi. I messed around with "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces" and "sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" according to some instructions on websites that I found while google-ing, but when I type "sudo ifup wlan0" it states that it couldn't start. Do I need to install some drivers or something? And, what happened to "wpa_gui"?(wpa_gui returns command not found). Should I try Wheezy instead of Jessie? I am using a raspberry Pi 2. Please help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39021/raspberry-pi-wifi-wont-work

Comment: Yea, that was me too, but that time I had forgotten my email password and posted as a guest. I didn't how to comment as a guest so I logged in and posted a new question, ALSO, the answer ("rfkill" command) didn't work. The command wasn't recognized.

Comment: 'ran a few commands' doesn't say anything. What commands did you run and what is/was the (relevant part of the) output? Also what's the USB ID of your device? Run `lsusb` to find out, it's in the format of `xxxx:xxxx`

Comment: relevant? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38434/31077.